# java - producer consumer pattern finish signal

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an application which applies the Producer-Consumer design pattern. IT is written in java. in short, the producers put items in a blocking queue and the consumers takes them from there. the consumers should run until signaled by a producer to stop.

what is the neatest way to deliver this signal from producers to the consumers? the chief designer said he wants to keep producer and consumer separate but I dont see any other other than invoking a method on consumer thread pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chief Programmer is right. Keeping them separate leads to highly decoupled code which is excellent.

There are several ways to do this. One of them is called Poison Pill. Here's how it works - place a known item on the Queue when the Consumer see that item, they kill themselves or take another action.

This can be tricky if there are multiple Consumers (you mentioned ThreadPool) or bounded Queues. Please look this up in Java Concurrency in Practice by Joshua Bloch. He explained it best.

Answer (score 1):

Send a cancel message through the queue.  Your consumers' `run` methods would look like

```
while(true) {
    Message message = queue.take();
    if(message == Message.Cancel) {
        queue.offer(message); // so that the other consumers can read the Cancel message
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a ConsumerHalter class. Register all consumers that wants to get data from queue to the ConsumerHalter class, and have producer trigger a halt event in the ConsumerHalther class. The ConsumerHalter class then calls onStopConsuming() of each consumers.